# How K-Means clustering help in the analysis of word2vec embeddings?

Tags: python, nlp, word-embedding

I am new to NLP. I have a yelp-review dataset. I have used a word2vector embedding on the text column of the yelp-review. I have used K-means and PCA to visualise the data and have obtained 6 clusters which are well separated. Now I want to know, what this six clusters represent. In other words, I want to see which "words" belongs to cluster 0 and so on.
I have used this code but the output is a lot of words.

```
for i, word in enumerate(words):  
    print (word + ":" + str(labels[i]))
```

labels are the k-means labels. I am thinking of an idea of a
word cloud with respect to the K-means cluster labels.

Please can one one give an idea how to do proceed.

I also a photo of the data frame head.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

"Top 10" is an ill defined notion. Top 10 most representative? 10 words defining the boundaries of the clusters? Something else?

However, considering this is a *qualitative* assessment of the performance of the algorithmic pipeline you've described, (rather than a *quantitative* metric), you probably just need to try a few things and see what "works", e.g what gives you insight...
Two obvious options that come to mind are the following:

1. Words from close to the cluster centroids: Each k-means cluster has a centroid (the mean of locations of points in the cluster), and points close to the center might be "strong" representatives of the underlying class.
2. Much more general - view the words in the (dimensionally-reduced) embedding space itself. Either in the feature space of the top two eigenvectors of the PCA you claim is working for you, or with something slightly more modern (and very much less linear) such as tsne.

There are many other options, but these are common practice and a good starting point.

---

Regarding comments: By the look of your df, it seems that for the list of words for cluster `i`, you just need to do something like -

```
list_of_words = df[i]['clean'].split()
```

But there's only so much one can do with an image of a dataframe, and this is beyond the scope of the original question anyway.

Comment: @ ShlomiF For example, is it possible to create a word cloud with respect to the cluster label '0'.

Comment: Of course. That's exactly the second option...each word has a vector associated with it. Using some form of dimension reduction to two dimensions, each word has an associated point (x, y). Just plot them out using matplotlib's `plt.text`. or use tsne (on all the clusters at once preferably).

Comment: Only question, remains is how do I slice the data-frame with respect to the cluster labels. Do you know how to do it.

Comment: Yes. But i'd need an example portion of said df.

Comment: df mean the data frame after processing.

Comment: I mean whatever dataframe **you** mentioned...But I'm thinking this is a separate `pandas` question; a different question from the one above, with need to open a new SO question, and also one with many many available answers.

Comment: @Spal - if this answer was of use to you, it's customary to upvote/accept. You seem new here, so in case you're unaware...